# Entity cannot be found by elasticsearch

Tags: entity-framework, elasticsearch

I have the following entity in ElasticSearch:

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "entity-id": 1019,
  "entity-name": "aaa",
  "status": "New",
  "creation-date": "2014-08-06",
  "author": "bubu"
}
```

I try to query for all entities with status=New, so the above entity should appear there.
I run this code:

```
qesponse.setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("status", "New"));
return qResponse.setFrom(start).setSize(size).execute().actionGet().toString();
```

But it return no result.

If I use this code (general search, not of specific field) I get the above entity.

```
qResponse.setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("New");
return qResponse.setFrom(start).setSize(size).execute().actionGet().toString();
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a mismatch between a Term Query and using the Standard Analyzer when you index. The Standard Analyzer, among other things, lowercases the field when it's indexed:

> **Standard Analyzer**
>
> An analyzer of type standard is built using the Standard Tokenizer
>   with the Standard Token Filter, Lower Case Token Filter, and Stop
>   Token Filter.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

The Term query, however, matches without analysis:

> **Term Query**
>
> Matches documents that have fields that contain a term (not analyzed).
>   The term query maps to Lucene TermQuery.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

So in your case when you index the field status it becomes "new". But when you search with a Term Query it's looking for "New" - they don't match. They do match with a general search it works because the general search also uses the Standard Analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of index for a string field is analyzed . So, when you write "status" = "New" , it will use standard_analyzer, and after analyzing it will write as "new" .

So, term Query doesn't seems to be working, If you wish to query like you specified ,write mapping for the field as "not_analyzed".

For more info. [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html)